# Building Sharepoint project on 32bit machine

Tags: sharepoint-2010, msbuild, teamcity, build-server

My buildserver is a 32bit system.

I heard that to run and develop sharepoint projects I need a 64bit machine.

Is it feasible to build a sharepoint project on a 32bit system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question:

It IS possible to build Sharepoint projects on a 32bit  4.0 Framework with msbuild. Also those can be deployed to a server.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no. You'll need an x64 box to build it on. Note that with team city you get 3 free build agent licenses so you can always toss the build on another machine.

Comment: btw.: It's not 3 build server licenses. You have 3 agent licenses.

Comment: @ckeller : thanks, we've got a one to one map of agent -> build server so the terms are a bit interchangeable in my head. Fixed.